# Get Elements position relative to screen in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, position, xamarin.forms

I have a list with context menu and while i'm clicking, list of options(Edit, Delete, Info) will shown in a pop-up.

Here i need to show this pop-up left below to the context menu icon, for that i need the position of the context menu relative to the screen.

Can anyone help me to get the XY position of an element in Xamarin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

This is my version of a method I found in the [Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/276291/#Comment_276291):

```
public static class ScreenCoords
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A view's default X- and Y-coordinates are LOCAL with respect to the boundaries of its parent,
    /// and NOT with respect to the screen. This method calculates the SCREEN coordinates of a view.
    /// The coordinates returned refer to the top left corner of the view.
    /// </summary>
    public static Point GetScreenCoords(this VisualElement view)
    {
        var result = new Point(view.X, view.Y);
        while (view.Parent is VisualElement parent)
        {
            result = result.Offset(parent.X, parent.Y);
            view = parent;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This method isn't returning the right coordinates on iOS (i think it ignores safe area), maybe you know any fix for this trouble?

Comment: it wont return the relative or absolute to screen. it returns only the positions to the parent view. So if you have a scrollview or stacklayout goes off the screen, it will return to the absolute x, y coordinates to the scrollview. To the screen is what is visible on the screen.

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit. Also note that **if you use `NavigationPage`, this won't include the height of the navigation bar!** _(at least on Android)_ There doesn't seem to be a way to get the navbar height from Xamarin Forms, so getting the actual screen coords seems to require [a custom `NavigationPageRenderer`](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/147029/what-is-default-height-of-navigation-bar).  Oof.

Comment: Scratch that, I did find a method to get the navbar height.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66962482/238419