# how can i get status bar height in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, size, statusbar

I am trying to get  status / action bar height  in my application.
I got some of how we can get it in native android.
can we  get status / action bar height in xamarin.forms ?if yes then how?
please help if anybody have idea about it.
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own dependency service. (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/)

In your shared code, create an interface for example IStatusBar:

```
public interface IStatusBar
    {
        int GetHeight();
    }
```

Add implementation for Android platform:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(StatusBar))]
namespace StatusBarApp.Droid
{
    class StatusBar : IStatusBar
    {
        public static Activity Activity { get; set; }

        public int GetHeight()
        {
            int statusBarHeight = -1;
            int resourceId = Activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0)
            {
                statusBarHeight = Activity.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
            return statusBarHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Activity property is set from MainActivity.cs:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            StatusBar.Activity = this;

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

This is how you call the implementation from the shared code:

```
int statusBarHeight = DependencyService.Get<IStatusBar>().GetHeight();
```

Implementation for IOS platform:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(StatusBar))]
namespace StatusBarApp.iOS
{
    class StatusBar : IStatusBar
    {
        public int GetHeight()
        {
            return (int)UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sooooooooooooooooooooooooo much. i was trying same but didnt knew about activity so wondering ant resourses.u saved me.

Comment: seeking for  one more help.i coudnt find for ios.can u share ios dependency too if you done?

Comment: I didn't have it but I implemented it.

Comment: i tired this already .but i dont think it gives right value.like m geeting 20 in ipad.but status bar seems bigger than 20.plese check image i updated

Comment: StatusBar is the thin bar above the NavigationBar and it is 20 pixels on ios. So you need tot make a sum between those two. You can get navigationBar height  from NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height.

Comment: oh...thnk u sooo much.

Comment: Using Xamarin.Essentials you can get android activity like so: `var activity = Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity;`

Answer (score 5):

**Common code (in App.xaml.cs)**

```
public static int StatusBarHeight {get; set;}
```

**Android part (in MainActivity.cs, in the OnCreate method)**

```
int resourceId = Resources.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0)
{
    App.StatusBarHeight = (int)(Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
}
```

**iOS part (in AppDelegate.cs, in the FinishedLaunching method)**

```
App.StatusBarHeight = (int)UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height;
```

So App.StatusBarHeight will be initialized when the App will be launched, then you will be able to use it anywhere in the common code.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers on this page did not work for me. They returned a value that was ~8 DP smaller than the actual status bar, causing all my calculations to be off.

Here is a pure Xamarin Forms solution that worked:

```
// Tested only in Android
private double NavbarHeight => 
    Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage navPage && navPage.CurrentPage != null
    ? navPage.Height - navPage.CurrentPage.Height
    : 0;
```

Unfortunately this relies on the assumption that all your Pages expand to their full parent container, which is not always true.

Also it returns the height in DP. If you want the height in pixels, multiply by `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density`

Comment: @DavidClarke Your suggested change changes the behavior as it does not check `CurrentPage` for null

Comment: Good point, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I used a dependency service like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using ProTrain.Droid.DependencyServices;
using ProTrain.Interfaces;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PlatformStuff))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.DependencyServices
{
    public class PlatformStuff : IPlatformStuff
    {
        internal static Func<Context> GetContext { get; set; }                        

        public int GetToolbarSize()
        {
            var Context = GetContext();
            TypedArray styledAttributes = Context.Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.ActionBarSize });
            var actionbar = (int)styledAttributes.GetDimension(0, 0);
            styledAttributes.Recycle();
            return actionbar;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the mainactivity I set the context:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    PlatformStuff.GetContext = () => this;
...
```