# How to get MAUI UI element absolute coordinates

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I'm developping a MAUI app and I want to show a popup at the coordinates of the button that initiated it. The code for generating the popup at the given coordinates works fine (using an absolute layout), but I'm having a hard time acquiring the coordinates.

The code from the following URL worked flawlessly in Xamarin, but it doesn't work in MAUI.

[How to get coordinates of the selected item in a list view in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263876/how-to-get-coordinates-of-the-selected-item-in-a-list-view-in-xamarin-forms)

This is my Xamarin version of what the first link suggests.

```
var renderer = xForms.Platform.UWP.Platform.GetRenderer(element);
var nativeView = renderer.GetNativeElement();
var element_Visual_Relative = nativeView.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
Point point = element_Visual_Relative.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
return new System.Drawing.PointF((int)Math.Round(point.X), (int)Math.Round(point.Y));
```

And this is my attempt at converting it to MAUI. It returns 0, 0.

```
var frameworkElement = element.ToPlatform(MauiProgram.Context);
var platformView = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Windows.First().Handler.PlatformView;
var visualRelativePoint = frameworkElement.TransformToVisual(platformView.Content);
var point = visualRelativePoint.TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0, 0));
return new Point((int)Math.Round(point.X), (int)Math.Round(point.Y));
```

Is someone versed enough in Maui to tell me what's wrong? I plan a release on WinUI, but input for other platforms, I'm sure, would be useful to all.

Thank you very much

P-S: Here's another solution, but it's very basic and doesn't handle list view items:

[Get Elements position relative to screen in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892518/get-elements-position-relative-to-screen-in-xamarin)

Update:

I tried @Liyun Zhang - MSFT's solution and it works! I revamped it to take into account navbar height, which appears to be applied systematically to coordinates event if it's invisible. Here's my latest version.

```
using uiXaml = Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

public override Point GetElementCoordinates(VisualElement element){
    var nativeWindow = (uiXaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First().Handler.PlatformView;
    var nativeElement = (uiXaml.UIElement)element.Handler.PlatformView;
    var coordinates = nativeElement .TransformToVisual(nativeWindow.Content)
                                    .TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0, 0));

    var navBarHeight = (App.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage navPage && navPage.CurrentPage != null) 
                     ? navPage.Height - navPage.CurrentPage.Height : 0;

    return new Point((int)Math.Round(coordinates.X), 
                     (int)Math.Round(coordinates.Y - navBarHeight));
}
```

Comment: Well I guess you can use TouchTracking for this, I am actually setting it up for MAUI and might add it on Nuget by Saturday or so, just trying to confirm from the original author that its ok for me to port it, https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyEffects/tree/dev you can use the code here if you want

Comment: @FreakyAli Sounds good! I guess, the position would be the one of the touch and not of the underlying control, but I can live with it. Please let us know if you manage to release a NuGet package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are two properties name X and Y for the maui's control. You can get it with the code such as: `button.X` or `button.Y`.

In addition, I have tried your code about getting the absolute coordinates and changed a little.

```
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
var platformview = CounterBtn.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiButton;
var point = platformview.TransformToVisual(window.Content).TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0, 0));
```

The platformview is a button and the point will get a value with X, Y different from the `button.X` or `button.Y`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This code worked and I could build my final version upon it.

Comment: I think this will only work for Windows since you access the platform namespace, the intellisense for this shows it will be missing for other operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

Both samples are very platform/control dependent; they only work for MAUI Windows and/or the element is a `MauiButton`.

A more general approach would be to take the x and y coordinates of an element and its parents and sum them up. This should work for all platforms (I tested Android/Windows).

`GetAbsolutePosition(` returns the top, left coordinates of the `VisualElement` provided as argument.

Get ancestors:

```
    public static IEnumerable<VisualElement> Ancestors(this VisualElement element)
    {
        while(element != null)
        {
            yield return element;
            element = element.Parent as VisualElement;
        }
    }
```

Sum up x and y:

```
    private static Point GetAbsolutePosition(VisualElement visualElement)
    {
        var ancestors = visualElement.Ancestors();
        var x = ancestors.Sum(ancestor => ancestor.X);
        var y = ancestors.Sum(ancestor => ancestor.Y);

        return new Point(x, y);
    }
```